# Сравнение и подсчет процентного совпадения по интересам у пользователей

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Столкнулся с серьёзной проблемой в разработке веб-сайта знакомств для курсовой. Создал всю внешнюю оболочку, обмен сообщениями и т.д., но остался сложный подбор людей по интересам.

Мне нужно, чтобы у пользователей хранились их процентные совпадения по интересам с другими пользователями, чтобы потом я мог находить им друзей. Но сейчас мне нужно конкретно находить процент совпадений.

Ниже прикладываю схему, логику действий, которую я не могу реализовать, и MySQL код таблиц.

Я уже посмотрел все схожие темы но не нашёл ничего столь запутанного, как моё задание. Прошу вашей помощи, вопрос жизни и смерти! 
[image: Схема базы]
Этот "цикл" будет отдельно для каждого Id_music, id_book и id_film, потому в описании они идут через /

1. При добавлении поля Id_music/id_book/id_film в таблицы Watched,Read,Listened создавать цикл, равный количеству пользователей минус 1. ID нашего пользователя заносится каждый раз на позицию user_one в таблицу Stats, а id того, с кем сравниваем - в user_two.
2. Считать количество записей по id в таблице Listened/Watched/Read, чтобы узнать общее количество интересов в этой категории у нашего пользователя. Тоже самое делаем для пользователя в цикле

3.Поочередно сравнивать поле ID_Music/ID_Book/ID_Film в таблице Read/Listened/Watched нашего пользователя на совпадение с теми же полями у другого пользователя, что сейчас в цикле. В итоге мы получим число совпадений.

4.Сравниваем это число с количеством записей этих пользователей из пункта 2. К примеру, если у нашего пользователя всего 4 записи , а у второго 8, и совпадений 2, мы заносим в таблицу stats 50(%) в поле bks_prcnt/msc_prcnt/flm_prcnt и 25(%) в поле bks_prcnt_rev/msc_prcnt_rev/flm_prcnt_rev, потому что у второго пользователя больше интересов.

5.?цикл заканчивается. Если поля существовали ранее - обновляем, а не создаём их.

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` ( 
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `username` text NOT NULL, 
 `password` text NOT NULL, 
 'about' text(500), 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8; 

 CREATE TABLE `stats` ( 
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `user_one` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 `user_two` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 `bks_prcnt` INT(4) NOT NULL , 
 `bks_prcnt_rev` INT(4) NOT NULL, 
 `flm_prcnt` INT(4) NOT NULL, 
 `flm_prcnt_rev` INT(4) NOT NULL, 
 `msc_prcnt` INT(4) NOT NULL, 
 `msc_prcnt_rev` INT(4) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
 FOREIGN KEY (user_one) REFERENCES users(id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (user_two) REFERENCES users(id) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8; 

 CREATE TABLE `genres` ( 
 `genre_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `genre_name` text NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`genre_id`) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8; 

 CREATE TABLE `music` ( 
 `music_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `title` text NOT NULL, 
 `id_genre` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 `Compositor` text NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`music_id`) , 
 FOREIGN KEY (id_genre) REFERENCES genres(genre_id) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8; 

 CREATE TABLE `book` ( 
 `book_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `title` text NOT NULL, 
 `id_genre` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 `Author` text NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`) , 
 FOREIGN KEY (id_genre) REFERENCES genres(genre_id) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8; 

 CREATE TABLE `film` ( 
 `film_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `title` text NOT NULL, 
 `id_genre` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 `Producer` text NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`), 
 FOREIGN KEY (id_genre) REFERENCES genres(genre_id) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8; 

 CREATE TABLE `Listened` ( 
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 `id_music` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`) , 
 FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users(id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (id_music) REFERENCES music(id) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8; 


 CREATE TABLE `Watched` ( 
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 `id_film` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`) , 
 FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users(id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (id_film) REFERENCES film(id) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8; 


 CREATE TABLE `Read` ( 
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 `id_book` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`) , 
 FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users(id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (id_book) REFERENCES book(id) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8;
```

и вот несколько Insert-ов (не обращайте внимание на схожесть жанров музыки, книг и фильмов)

```
 INSERT INTO `Users`(`id`, `username`, `password`, `about`) VALUES ('','User1','213','something')
 INSERT INTO `Users`(`id`, `username`, `password`, `about`) VALUES ('','User2','313','something')
 INSERT INTO `genres`(`genre_id`, `genre_name`) VALUES ('','Genre1')
 INSERT INTO `genres`(`genre_id`, `genre_name`) VALUES ('','Genre2')
 INSERT INTO `genres`(`genre_id`, `genre_name`) VALUES ('','Genre3')
 INSERT INTO `book`(`book_id`, `title`,'id_genre','Author') VALUES ('','Book1','1','Author1')
 INSERT INTO `book`(`book_id`, `title`,'id_genre','Author') VALUES ('','Book2','2','Author2')
 INSERT INTO `music`(`music_id`, `title`,'id_genre','Compositor') VALUES ('','Song1','1','Compositor1')
 INSERT INTO `music`(`music_id`, `title`,'id_genre','Compositor') VALUES ('','Song2','2','Compositor2')
 INSERT INTO `film`(`film_id`, `title`,'id_genre','Producer') VALUES ('','Film1','1','Producer1')
 INSERT INTO `film`(`film_id`, `title`,'id_genre','Producer') VALUES ('','Film2','2','Producer2')
 INSERT INTO `Read`(`id`, `id_user,'id_book') VALUES ('','1','1')
 INSERT INTO `Read`(`id`, `id_user,'id_book') VALUES ('','1','2')
 INSERT INTO `Read`(`id`, `id_user,'id_book') VALUES ('','2','1')
 INSERT INTO `Listened`(`id`, `id_user,'id_music') VALUES ('','1','1')
 INSERT INTO `Listened`(`id`, `id_user,'id_music') VALUES ('','1','2')
 INSERT INTO `Listened`(`id`, `id_user,'id_music') VALUES ('','2','1')
 INSERT INTO `Watched`(`id`, `id_user,'id_film') VALUES ('','1','1')
 INSERT INTO `Watched`(`id`, `id_user,'id_film') VALUES ('','1','2')
 INSERT INTO `Watched`(`id`, `id_user,'id_film') VALUES ('','2','1')
```

Comment: Пусть есть пользователи ID 1 и ID 2. В таблице stats будет две записи 1-2 и 2-1 или только одна. если одна - то какая именно. Если две - то зачем надо хранить в записи процент прямой и процент обратный, если можно было бы хранить только процент в одном направлении и из вашего примера у записи 1-2 будет 50% у 2-1 25%

Comment: Да, и не могли бы вы еще в коде создания таблиц положить несколько insert с тестовыми данными

Comment: Изначально думал, как вы и сказали, хранить 1-2 и 2-1, и в каждом разное значение процентов, но потом решил ввести прямой и обратный процент. В этом случае я хотел бы хранить на первом месте id пользователя, который вносит изменения в id_book,id_music и т.д. но не уверен, что это лучше чем изначальный вариант.
Сейчас отредактирую и добавлю Insertы с юзерами, книгами и другим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы работаете с SQL базой данных. SQL позволяет получить любые данные в любом нужном виде и в 99% случаев это делается одним запросом. Если при работе с SQL вам приходится использовать "цикл" и этот цикл предназначен не для вывода готовых данных из БД на клиента - то скорее всего вы что то делаете не так. Полное содержимое для таблицы `stats` можно получить следующим запросом:

```
select u1, u2,
       max(prcnt*(source='Read')) as bks_prcnt,
       max(prcnt_rev*(source='Read')) as bks_prcnt_rev,
       max(prcnt*(source='List')) as flm_prcnt,
       max(prcnt_rev*(source='List')) as flm_prcnt_rev,
       max(prcnt*(source='Watch')) as msc_prcnt,
       max(prcnt_rev*(source='Watch')) as msc_prcnt_rev
  from (
  select * from (
    select least(u1,u2) u1, greatest(u1,u2) u2, 'Read' as source,
           max((u1<u2)*prcnt) prcnt, max((u1>u2)*prcnt) prcnt_rev
      from (
        select R1.id_user u1, R2.id_user u2, round(count(1)*100/R.all_cnt) prcnt
          from `Read` R1, `Read` R2,
               (
                select id_user u, count(1) all_cnt
                  from `Read`
                 group by id_user
               ) R
         where R1.id_book=R2.id_book and R1.id_user!=R2.id_user and R.u=R1.id_user
         group by R1.id_user, R2.id_user
        ) A
     group by least(u1,u2), greatest(u1,u2)
   ) A
  UNION ALL
  select * from (
    select least(u1,u2) u1, greatest(u1,u2) u2, 'List' as source,
           max((u1<u2)*prcnt) prcnt, max((u1>u2)*prcnt) prcnt_rev
      from (
        select R1.id_user u1, R2.id_user u2, round(count(1)*100/R.all_cnt) prcnt
          from `Listened` R1, `Listened` R2,
               (
                select id_user u, count(1) all_cnt
                  from `Listened`
                 group by id_user
               ) R
         where R1.id_music=R2.id_music and R1.id_user!=R2.id_user and R.u=R1.id_user
         group by R1.id_user, R2.id_user
        ) A
     group by least(u1,u2), greatest(u1,u2)
   ) A
  UNION ALL
  select * from (
    select least(u1,u2) u1, greatest(u1,u2) u2, 'Watch' as source, 
           max((u1<u2)*prcnt) prcnt, max((u1>u2)*prcnt) prcnt_rev
      from (
        select R1.id_user u1, R2.id_user u2, round(count(1)*100/R.all_cnt) prcnt
          from `Watched` R1, `Watched` R2,
               (
                select id_user u, count(1) all_cnt
                  from `Watched`
                 group by id_user
               ) R
         where R1.id_film=R2.id_film and R1.id_user!=R2.id_user and R.u=R1.id_user
         group by R1.id_user, R2.id_user
        ) A
     group by least(u1,u2), greatest(u1,u2)
   ) B
 ) C
```

Если записей в БД не много - то можно всегда получать нужные данные на лету. Если тормозит - то можно их, конечно, кешировать в таблице `stats`. Запрос легко переделывается для получения похожих пользователей относительно конкретного. Для этого надо добавить условия с ID нужного пользователя во все 3 подзапроса для алиасов R1, а так же в самый глубокий подзапрос получающий all_cnt.

Вообще запрос мог бы быть гораздо проще и короче, если бы вы не захотели в одной записи видеть как прямой так и обратный процент. Из за него приходится сначала получать эти 2 процента отдельными строками, а потом затягивать в одну строку группировкой по `least(), greatest()` (которая оставляет только строки где первый ID меньше второго).

Так же данный запрос был бы в 3 раза короче (и заодно упростилась бы работа с БД практически везде) если бы вы свели таблицы Book/Music/Film в одну, просто добавив в запись поле "тип контента" и сведя равнозначные поля к одному. После этого таблицы Read/Listed/Watched так же сводятся в одну таблицу и мы можем посчитать как общий процент так и проценты в разрезе типов контента управляя фразой `group by` в одном коротком запросе.

А что до таблицы stats, то если она понадобится, из нее следует удалить поле `id`, первичный ключ сделать `PRIMARY KEY (user_one, user_two)`. После этого писать/обновлять данные в ней можно будет как:

```
insert into stats
select ВОТ_ТОТ_БОЛЬШОЙ_ЗАПРОС
on duplicate key update bks_prcnt=values(bks_prcnt),
                        bks_prcnt_rev=values(bks_prcnt_rev), ...
```

Итого: Подучите SQL, он на самом деле довольно простой, несколько базовых элементов можно вкладывать друг в друга сколько угодно глубоко и описывать любой разрез данных. Изучать можно как раз по запросу вверху, берите из него небольшие куски, отдельно их пробуйте, смотрите что они дают, экспериментируйте. И запомните, в SQL нет вопроса "*можно ли* это сделать", есть только вопрос "*как* это сделать".

P.S. Многих наверняка напряжет "странная" запись `max((u1<u2)*prcnt)`, такая короткая запись поддерживается только в MySQL. Он при вычислении любого сравнения выдает арифметический `0` если условие ложно и 1 если истинно. Поэтому можно использовать операции сравнения в арифметике. Данный `max()` берет только значения записей где `u1<u2`, умножая количество на 0 или 1. В других СУБД потребовалась бы запись `max(case when u1<u2 then prcnt end)`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за столь точный  ответ и пояснение как переделать на другие базы. Сейчас буду проверять!

Answer (score 0):

Хранить процентное соотношение неправильно по целому ряду причин:

1. Вам нужно будет пересчитывать при добавлении нового пользователя
2. Вам нужно будет пересчитывать при изменении существующего пользователя

   И это для всех пользователей.

Лучше динамически рассчитывать (кешировать для скорости повторного доступа).
Алгоритм следующий:

1. Берем ID Нашего пользователя.
2. Выбираем все его книги
3. Для каждой книги ищем ID пользователей и заносим в словарь ID => счётчик (т.е. если в словаре есть ID, то увеличиваем на 1 счётчик)
4. Тоже самое делаем с фильмами и музыкой.
5. Получаем что-то вроде этого:

   005 => 20,  // наш пользователь
   023 => 10,
   024 => 05,
   007 => 18,
   123 => 03;
6. Теперь мы можем поделить счетчики каждого пользователя со счетчиком нашего и получить процентное соотношение совпадений.

Не знаю как по скорости. Наверняка можно улучшить алгоритм (например подсчитывать кол-во совпадений для всех книг\фильмов\музыки нашего пользователя).

Comment: Я согласен, что пересчитывать каждый раз при добавлении/удалении связи id_интерес не практично, но на данный момент это уже закреплённая за мной задача, и я пытаюсь её решить.

Но в рамках диплома я рад буду поменять метод, хотя не до конца понимаю что вы предлагаете в 3 пункте под словарь ID => счетчик. 
Вы предлагаете сравнивать не интересы двух пользователей, а интересы одного пользователя на совпадения с другими?(не знаю, как точнее сказать)

Comment: @TigranOganov, совершенно верно. Ведь в конечном итоге для пользователя это и нужно. Никто вам не мешает это решение модифицировать для всех пользователей, но повторюсь: хранить % в базе - плохая идея.